# Implementing a Coda Slider Stop / Pause / Play Button

Tags: jquery, coda-slider

I am trying to implement Coda Slider on a website's homepage and the person I'm doing it for asked for a stop button, but there is little to no documentation on the matter. Has anyone faced this issue before?

Coda Slider: http://www.ndoherty.biz/
My website: http://enguita.info

Answer (score 0):

Found this in the comments section of the Coda-Slider documentation:

> emceehao wrote: hi, this is an amazing slider. but i want to stop the
>   loop, is it possible?
>
> Code:
>
> ```
> function autoSlide() {
>    if (navClicks == 0 || !settings.autoSlideStopWhenClicked) {
>       if (currentPanel == panelCount) {
>          return false; ////////add this line///////////
>          var offset = 0;
>          currentPanel = 1;
>       } else {...
> ```
>
> crude but it works. if you want some to do it and some not, add an
>   entry to the settings array like "stopAtEnd" and test for it like
>   if(settings.stopAtEnd)

(PS is it OK to post an answer from another forum...?)

Comment: Was this answer helpful to you?